# ORA-01858 Error in an Oracle SQL Table

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert, sqldatatypes

I've been fighting with this problem for a few days.

I created the next table in Oracle's SQL Developer:

```
CREATE TABLE EMPLEADOSMM (
ID_EMPLEADO VARCHAR2 (10) PRIMARY KEY,
NOMBREEM VARCHAR2 (15) NOT NULL,
AP_PATEM VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
AP_MATEM VARCHAR2 (20) NOT NULL,
FECHA_NAC DATE NOT NULL,
FECHA_ING DATE NOT NULL,
ID_CARGO VARCHAR2 (10));
```

Then, I proceeded to add some values to the table, the thing is that it added some like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM VALUES ('100006','OSCAR','MARIN','PEREZ','12-jul-85','15-nov-17','C0002');
```

But this others send me the 'ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected' error.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM VALUES ('100004','FABIAN','RODRIGUEZ','VELEZ','31-aug-87','13-jul-17','C0003');
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM VALUES ('100005','LUZ MARIA','TORINO','YAÑEZ','11-dec-90','13-jul-17','C0003');
```

I tried changing the year format by "yyyy", rewriting all the zeros, but nothings seems to work. Some ideas?

Comment: Could you show how have you tried doing that? `ORA-01858` in specific says that a non-numeric character is found where a numeric is expected

Comment: The problem is your default date format is not `dd-mon-yy`, so u can't use strings of  that form while inserting dates. Either use date literal for dates : `DATE '1985-07-12'`  or `TO_DATE ( '12-jul-1985','dd-mon-yyyy')`  instead of  plainly using  `'12-jul-85'` . Same for `'15-nov-17'`

Comment: Ok, thanks @KaushikNayak it worked, but it actually accepted the `'15-nov-17'`, I don't  understand why the others don't.

@N00bPr0grammer the lines I describe before are the actuall code I tried to used and did'nt work

Comment: Look at these two SQLs : `select to_char(date'2017-11-15','mon','nls_date_language=spanish'), 
       to_char(date'2017-11-15','mon','nls_date_language=english')
  from dual;` and
`select to_char(date'1987-08-31','mon','nls_date_language=spanish'), 
       to_char(date'1987-08-31','mon','nls_date_language=english')
  from dual;`, i think why '15-nov-17' accepted but others weren't. By the way, dates of `july` should also be accepted.

Comment: And always specify the column names in the insert statement. `Insert into tablename(col1,col2,col3) values (valu1,valu2,val3) `, Or else you might end up inserting wrongly.

Comment: The names of the months in Spanish are Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre. You were lucky with `Jul` and `Nov` but it failed for `Aug` and  `Dec`. (Maybe it also guessed your centuries correctly, maybe it didn't.) I once worked on a system where a date string like this was deployed to production in November and failed in the Paris office in February.

Answer (score 2):

First, I want to emphasize that the code *does* work.  [Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/eeee5) is a SQL Fiddle demonstrating the working code.

Second, that means that something about your system causes it to break.  Barbaras Ozhan seems to have the right explanation -- internationalization settings recognize some month abbreviations as being the same as English, but not all of them.

You should be writing the insert as:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM (ID_EMPLEADO, NOMBREEM, AP_PATEM, AP_MATEM, FECHA_NAC, FECHA_ING, ID_CARGO)
    VALUES ('100006', 'OSCAR', 'MARIN', 'PEREZ', DATE '1985-07-12', DATE '2017-11-15', 'C0002');

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM (ID_EMPLEADO, NOMBREEM, AP_PATEM, AP_MATEM, FECHA_NAC, FECHA_ING, ID_CARGO)
    VALUES ('100004', 'FABIAN', 'RODRIGUEZ', 'VELEZ', DATE '1987-08-31', DATE '2017-07-13', 'C0003');

INSERT INTO EMPLEADOSMM (ID_EMPLEADO, NOMBREEM, AP_PATEM, AP_MATEM, FECHA_NAC, FECHA_ING, ID_CARGO)
    VALUES ('100005', 'LUZ MARIA', 'TORINO', 'YAÑEZ', DATE '1990-12-11', DATE '2017-07-13', 'C0003');
```

Oracle supports the ANSI standard keyword `DATE` for introducing date constants in the ISO/ANSI standard format, YYYY-MM-DD.  I strongly recommend that you use this format in all your code.  Use `TIMESTAMP` when there is a time component.

Including the column names is a best practice.

I would question why the employee id is a string, if you are only going to include numbers in it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation and the best practice advise!, 'bout the question, it's for a project in my school and I was thinking about giving it an "E" letter at the beginning of the id, but idk, I just ignored it, I guess.